# path does not exist after being created with tmp_path fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, pytest-bdd

Edit: here's a git repo for easy testing:

https://gitlab.com/qualisign/ugit-bdd/

I want to refactor some repeated code from a step_def file to a `conftest.py` file.  Here's what the step_def looks like:

```
@scenario('../features/CLI.feature',
          'store file in object database')

def test_file_stored_by_content_address():
    pass

@given("a file exists at some full path within a ugit dir", target_fixture="file_exists_at_path")
def file_exists_at_path(file_within_ugit_dir):
    return file_within_ugit_dir

@when("I enter ugit hash-object followed by that path")
def file_gets_hashed(file_exists_at_path):
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_exists_at_path)
    base_name = os.path.basename(file_exists_at_path)
    os.chdir(dir_name)
    os.system(f'ugit hash-object {base_name}')

@then("this object is stored in a content-addressed location in the subdirectory .ugit/objects")
def object_saved_in_db(file_within_ugit_dir, file_hashed):
    with open(file_hashed, "rb") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        with open(file_path, "rb") as hf:
            assert hf.read() == f.read()
```

And here's the `conftest.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess
import hashlib
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers

WISE_WORDS = "Don\\'t be a fool!  I\\'ll call you later."

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def is_ugit_dir(tmp_path_factory):
    path = tmp_path_factory.mktemp('data')
    os.chdir(path)
    subprocess.run(['ugit', 'init'])
    return path

@pytest.fixture
def file_within_ugit_dir(is_ugit_dir):
    path = is_ugit_dir
    full_path = f'{path}/wise_words.txt'
    os.system(f'echo {WISE_WORDS} > wise_words.txt')
    return full_path


   
 @pytest.fixture
def file_hashed(is_ugit_dir, file_within_ugit_dir):
    """
    Returns the full path to a hash-object within the objects database
    """
    subprocess.run(['ugit', 'hash-object', file_within_ugit_dir])
    # there should now be a file with a sha1 content-address in the following directory
    objects_dir = os.path.dirname(is_ugit_dir)+'/.ugit/objects/'
    with open(file_within_ugit_dir, "rb") as f:
        # first calculate the hash
        sha_hash = hashlib.sha1 (f.read()).hexdigest ()
        return objects_dir+sha_hash
```

When I run the test, it seems that the temporary directory is not being kept open between steps:

```
t-74/.ugit/objects/7b5ee3d8d42c66048125a3937a0170ffdaf7b272'

    @then("this object is stored in a content-addressed location in the subdirectory .ugit/objects")
    def object_saved_in_db(file_hashed):
>       with open(file_hashed, "rb") as f:
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/m2/99x5jvw95ll6sbtgvj5md9700000gp/T/pytest-of-davidjoseph/pytest-74/.ugit/objects/7b5ee3d8d42c66048125a3937a0170ffdaf7b272'

/Users/davidjoseph/projects/ugit-bdd/tests/step_defs/test_cli.py:43: FileNotFoundError
-------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------
Initialized empty ugit repository in /private/var/folders/m2/99x5jvw95ll6sbtgvj5md9700000gp/T/pytest-of-davidjoseph/pytest-74/data1/.ugit
7b5ee3d8d42c66048125a3937a0170ffdaf7b272
```

Is there any way to kee this temp directory open to be reused between fixtures in the `conftest.py` file, and eventually in the step_def file?

Comment: Make `is_ugit_dir` session-scoped by changing the deco to `@pytest.fixture(scope='session')`

Comment: @hoefling.  It still breaks at the same line when `is_ugit_dir` is session-scoped.  The only difference is that `is_ugit_dir` appears not be create a new tmp_dir for the `file_hashed`.  But it's still not available across files, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the scope of the `is_ugit_dir` fixture to `"session"` as suggested in the comment is sufficient; all the rest are the errors in your own code:

1. > ```
   > path = tmp_path_factory.mktemp('data')
   > os.chdir(path)
   > subprocess.run(['ugit', 'init'])
   > ```

   You change the current working directory to `/tmp/pytest-smth/data` and invoke `ugit init` in there - I assume the tool creates repository metadata at `/tmp/pytest-smth/data/.ugit` then. Later, you use

   > ```
   > objects_dir = os.path.dirname(is_ugit_dir)+'/.ugit/objects/'
   > ```

   to create the objects dir - this will get you `/tmp/pytest-smth/.ugit/objects`. No wonder this directory doesn't exist. Changing it to e.g. `objects_dir = is_ugit_dir / '.ugit' / 'objects'` fixes the first error. As a follow-up, the return of `file_hashed` fixture has to be changed to `objects_dir / sha_hash` to work with `pathlib` paths.
2. > ```
   > contents = f.read()
   > with open(file_path, "rb") as hf:
   >     assert hf.read() == f.read()
   > ```

   Aside that `file_path` is not defined (I guess this should be `file_within_ugit_dir`), you are reading the file into `contents` and then again. Why that? Either rewind the file via `f.seek(0)` before invoking `f.read()` again or use `contents` for comparison.

Here's the full working code, with minimal necessary changes:

#### `conftest.py`

```
import os
import subprocess
import hashlib
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers

WISE_WORDS = "Don\\'t be a fool!  I\\'ll call you later."


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def is_ugit_dir(tmp_path_factory):
    path = tmp_path_factory.mktemp('data')
    os.chdir(path)
    subprocess.run(['ugit', 'init'])
    return path


@pytest.fixture
def file_within_ugit_dir(is_ugit_dir):
    path = is_ugit_dir
    full_path = path / 'wise_words.txt'
    os.system(f'echo {WISE_WORDS} > wise_words.txt')
    return full_path


@pytest.fixture
def file_hashed(is_ugit_dir, file_within_ugit_dir):
    """
    Returns the full path to a hash-object within the objects database
    """
    subprocess.run(['ugit', 'hash-object', file_within_ugit_dir])
    # there should now be a file with a sha1 content-address in the following directory
    objects_dir = is_ugit_dir / '.ugit' / 'objects'
    with open(file_within_ugit_dir, "rb") as f:
        # first calculate the hash
        data = b'blob\x00' + f.read()  # prepend the object type
        sha_hash = hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
        return objects_dir / sha_hash
```

#### `step_def.py`

```
import os
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers


@scenario('features/CLI.feature', 'store file in object database')
def test_file_stored_by_content_address():
    pass


@given("a file exists at some full path within a ugit dir", target_fixture="file_exists_at_path")
def file_exists_at_path(file_within_ugit_dir):
    return file_within_ugit_dir


@when("I enter ugit hash-object followed by that path")
def file_gets_hashed(file_exists_at_path):
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_exists_at_path)
    base_name = os.path.basename(file_exists_at_path)
    os.chdir(dir_name)
    os.system(f'ugit hash-object {base_name}')

@then("this object is stored in a content-addressed location in the subdirectory .ugit/objects")
def object_saved_in_db(file_within_ugit_dir, file_hashed):
    with open(file_hashed, "rb") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip(b"blob\x00")
        with open(file_within_ugit_dir, "rb") as hf:
            assert hf.read() == contents
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have logic issue in your code.
According to the test scenario the fixture **file_hashed** must return a path to the **existing** file containing hash. One can see it here:

```
@then("this object is stored in a content-addressed location in the subdirectory .ugit/objects")
def object_saved_in_db(file_within_ugit_dir, file_hashed):
    with open(file_hashed, "rb") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        with open(file_path, "rb") as hf:
            assert hf.read() == f.read()
```

In the **conftest.py** you are not creating the file containing hash. You are creating a dummy link instead, and because there is nothing on that link, you get FileNotFoundError. Error is here (you code does not create a hash file):

```
@pytest.fixture
def file_hashed(is_ugit_dir, file_within_ugit_dir):
    objects_dir = os.path.dirname(is_ugit_dir)+'/.ugit/objects/'
    with open(file_within_ugit_dir, "rb") as f:
        # first calculate the hash
        sha_hash = hashlib.sha1 (f.read()).hexdigest ()
        return objects_dir+sha_hash
```

Comment: Good catch - that was definitely not intended.  I fixed it, though, and I'm still getting the same bug.  Updated my code so you can see the current state.  Also added a git repo to make testing easier.